# Why can ethanoic acid not be used in the production of paracetamol?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Ethanoyl chloride or ethanoic anhydride can be used but not ethanoic acid. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

In the preparation of paracetamol, the last step is the nucleophilic attack of the $\ce{-NH2}$ group of p-aminophenol on ethanoyl chloride or ethanoic anhydride. The last step is a selective attack by $\ce{-NH2}$ group and not by $\ce{-OH}$ group , which has to be taken care of.

Now you should agree that the ease of nucleophilic acyl substitution follows the trend as:

$$\ce{CH3COCl > CH3COOCOCH3 > CH3COOR > CH3COOH > CH3CONH2}$$
(simply compare the electrophilicity of carbonyl carbon and strength of the bond between carbonyl carbon and $\ce{-OH}$ or $\ce{-OH}$ substituted groups or stability of the leaving groups.)

So, the nucleophilic acyl substitution happens more easily in ethanoyl chloride or ethanoic anhydride than in ethanoic acid. As the transition state has much lower energy in the former two cases, hence the kinetically favoured attack (by $\ce{-NH2}$; as this is better nucleophile than $\ce{-OH}$)  is more feasible. But as the difficulty in substitution increases, the transition state energy increases and the competition between $\ce{-NH2 }$ and $\ce{-OH}$ increases and the yield of paracetamol will decreases.

That is why easily substitutable reagents will enhance the yield and hence should be used.